# Grouping xml data to multiple requests

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I am stuck on a scenario where I have to take data from a XML and make 3 web service request from it.
    EX:

```
<Data>
<Line>
<order>1</order>
<id>10</id>
<amount>10</amount>
<tax>5</tax>
</Line>
<Line>
<order>3</order>
<id>15</id>
<amount>10</amount>
<tax>5</tax>
</Line>
<Line>
<order>1</order>
<id>19</id>
<amount>10</amount>
<tax>5</tax>
</Line>
<Line>
<order>2</order>
<id>12</id>
<amount>10</amount>
<tax>5</tax>
</Line>
<Line>
<order>1</order>
<id>11</id>
<amount>10</amount>
<tax>5</tax>
</Line>
</Data>
```

So if you see there are three orders so i need to have 3 requests. Like:

```
<Order>
<no>1</no>
<totalamount>30</totalamount>
<totaltax>15</totaltax>
<list>
<id>10<id>
<id>19<id>
<id>11<id>
</list>
</Order>
<Order>
<no>2</no>
<totalamount>10</totalamount>
<totaltax>5</totaltax>
<list>
<id>12<id>
</list>
</Order>
```

Am thinking of creating a combined xml and splitting on element order to create multiple requests. How do I approach to do this in XSL.

Comment: Please post your XSLT tried...

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. Do a search, it's probably the most often asked question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: "*So if you see there are three orders so i need to have 3 requests.*" Then why does your output show only two? Note also that the output shown does not have a single root element; this is not allowed in XML.

Comment: I have to do this in XSLT 1.0. And to answer the above question , I think it would be easier to generate separate blocks and then split it in element order.

Comment: @Yauza Grouping in XSLT 1.0 is done using the Muenchian method. Read the article [here](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) and study the many examples posted on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Data">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="Line" group-by="order">
    <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
    <Order>
      <no><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></no>
      <totalamount><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/amount)"/></totalamount>
      <totaltax><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/tax)"/></totaltax>
      <list>
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
          <id><xsl:value-of select="id"/></id>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </list>
    </Order>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Order>
   <no>1</no>
   <totalamount>30</totalamount>
   <totaltax>15</totaltax>
   <list>
      <id>10</id>
      <id>19</id>
      <id>11</id>
   </list>
</Order>
<Order>
   <no>2</no>
   <totalamount>10</totalamount>
   <totaltax>5</totaltax>
   <list>
      <id>12</id>
   </list>
</Order>
<Order>
   <no>3</no>
   <totalamount>10</totalamount>
   <totaltax>5</totaltax>
   <list>
      <id>15</id>
   </list>
</Order>
```

Tested by this [Online XSLT processor](http://xslttest.appspot.com/).

**Update.**

For XSLT 1.0 the same transform can be done using [Muenchian grouping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT/Muenchian_grouping) method:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="lines-by-order" match="Line" use="order"/>

<xsl:template match="Data">
  <xsl:for-each select="Line[count(. | key('lines-by-order', order)[1]) = 1]">
    <xsl:sort select="order"/>
    <Order>
      <no><xsl:value-of select="order"/></no>
      <totalamount><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('lines-by-order', order)/amount)"/></totalamount>
      <totaltax><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('lines-by-order', order)/tax)"/></totaltax>
      <list>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('lines-by-order', order)/id"/>
      </list>
    </Order>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `<xsl:for-each select="current-group()"><id><xsl:value-of select="id"/></id>
</xsl:for-each>` can be shortened to `<xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/id"/>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitry, you have given me an approach to start with. Is this possible with XSLT 1.0 as my application does not support 2.0 till now.